# calculating the area of an irregular shape with shapely

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, shapely

I am trying to calculate the area of an irregular shape. The general procedure is to get a scan of the object, convert it to xyz data, and plot it in python to get the area of the surface of the plot(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPLk4.png). I used the package shapely, classified it as a polygon and calculated the area. However, the area is about a magnitude off. the data is exported in mm^2. Here is the simple code I have

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon 
pgon = Polygon(zip(x,y))
print(pgon.area)
13724.263247835068
```

I used a rectangular prism object first, to make sure that the area being calculated was accurate. The area of the surface should be 1200 mm^2, but as you can see from the code its about a whole magnitude larger than what it should be. I used convex hull and got a closer number, but my advisor is not a fan of using convex hull as it excludes points from the shape. I am open to using a different package to try to get this to work.

Comment: It is a bit unclear from your description what your x,y data actually are — shapely expects ordered points around the outer ring of a polygon, but your data looks more like some sort of point cloud? If that is the case, I suspect that Shapely is the wrong tool for the job, though you might get something useful if you use the `concave_hull` first.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.